# Android activity lifecycle - activity restarts when coming from history

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a splash activity (A) that calls a listview activity (B) which calls another activity (C).
When I'm on activity C and I press Home, than kill the app (or wait of Android to do it), than longpress Home and come back to activity C there's a strange problem:
When I click back I go back to B. Than I have a backbutton handler that asks the user if they want to exit and calls finish() on the activity. When I try to exit in this scenario, activity A starts again.

On regular operation it finishes B and doesn't go back to A.
Why is that??

Thanks

Comment: When you say "when I try to exit in this scenario", what do you mean by "exit"? How do you "exit"?

Comment: You mean you catch the back button press in ActivityB and try to call `finish()` on ActvityA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is killed (either by you or by Android) the process hosting your applications is killed. However, Android remembers the state of the activity stack (in your case A->B->C).

When the user returns to the app, Android creates a new process for the app and recreates **only the activity that was at the top of the activity stack** (in this case: C). Now the user presses BACK, which causes activity C to finish and Android recreates the instance of activity B which is then shown (You will see calls to `B.onCreate()`, `B.onStart()` and `B.onResume()`).

Now the user presses BACK again. Your back button handler tries to call `finish()` on activity A, but there is no instance of activity A. Android hasn't created it yet! When activity B finishes Android remembers that there was an instance of activity A in the activity stack underneath B so it recreates the instance of activity A which is then shown (You will see calls to `A.onCreate()`, `A.onStart()` and `A.onResume()`).

I hope this explains what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling finish() on A when you load B

Comment: Thanks! That seems to solve to solve the problem.
BTW - on ICS it happened even without killing the app - on finish() of activity B it restarted A. Very strange.

Comment: Activity Stacks can be complex at first, takes some time to understand their power :) If you could please accept an answer that would be great